# IE9 doesn't load video from remote host

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video, jplayer

I'm using jPlayer and it's working in all browsers except IE 9. If i open the page from a local location as '\192....\index.html', everything works... but if i open the page from the domain name 'http://dominename/... index.html', the video doesn't works.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a similar issue on safari with mp4 files. sounds like either you didn't upload your video to the right path (but I guess you checked it several times) or your server has problems with the mime types on ie. did you set mime types in your source like.

```
 <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

or set mime type via .htaccess file

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
```